# How to check if a specific integer is in a list

Tags: python, list, if-statement, python-2.7, int

I want to know how to make an if statement that executes a clause if a certain integer is in a list.

All the other answers I've seen ask for a specific condition like prime numbers, duplicates, etc. and I could not glean the solution to my problem from the others.

Comment: If you need to check if a specific integer is in a `list` a lot, you are better of converting your `list` to a `set`, and check if the integer is in the `set`.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

You could simply use the `in` keyword. Like this :

```
if number_you_are_looking_for in list:
    # your code here
```

For instance :

```
myList = [1,2,3,4,5]

if 3 in myList:
    print("3 is present")
```

Answer (score 8):

Are you looking for this?:

```
if n in my_list:
    ---do something---
```

Where `n` is the number you're checking. For example:

```
my_list = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
if 1 in my_list:
    print 'True'
```

Answer (score -2):

I think the above answers are wrong because of this situation:

```
my_list = [22166, 234, 12316]
if 16 in my_list: 
     print( 'Test 1 True' )
 else: 
      print( 'Test 1 False' ) 

my_list = [22166]
if 16 in my_list: 
    print( 'Test 2 True' )
else: 
    print( 'Test 2 False'  )
```

Would produce: 
Test 1 False 
Test 2 True

A better way:

```
if ininstance(my_list, list) and 16 in my_list: 
    print( 'Test 3 True' )
elif not ininstance(my_list, list) and 16 == my_list: 
    print( 'Test 3 True' )
else: 
    print( 'Test 3 False' )
```

Comment: This answer is wrong. The first stanza produces: Test 1 False, Test 2 False, as one would expect intuitively from python. You should remove this answer, it makes no sense.

Comment: 16 in [216] produces False; that is, @datashaman is correct; an int is not a string.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to see a specific number then you use `in` keyword but let say if you have

`list2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]`

Then what you can do. You simply do this:

```py
list2 = ['a','b','c','d','e','f',1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
for i in list2:
if isinstance(x , int):
    print(x)
```

this will only print integer which is present in a given list.

Comment: if isinstance(x , int):
    print(x)

Should be?
if isinstance(i , int):
    print(i)